# How to find an algebraic term when 2 similar exponential forms of it are given?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation

if $a^2bc^3 = 25$   and  $ab^2= 5$,  how would you find $abc$?

Is there a formula of which these are a part of? 
What I've done is this:

$$abc^3 = \frac{25}a\quad\implies\quad abc = \frac{25}{ac^2}$$

But how would I use the $ab^2$?

Comment: Please use Latex

Comment: What you wrote was unambiguous, but it would be a good idea to learn the basics of $\LaTeX$ so as to make your posts more readable; you can get a very good start [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Thanks, I'll sure take a look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\left(a^2bc^3\right)\left(ab^2\right)=a^3b^3c^3=(abc)^3$. Can you finish it from here?